# Unquoting argument inside of function in R

Tags: r, dplyr, quotes, quasiquotes

I cannot figure out why the bang-bang operator in my function is not unquoting my `grp` argument. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
library(dplyr)

test_func <- function(dat, grp){
  dat %>%
    group_by(!!grp) %>%
    summarise(N =  n())
}

test_func(dat = iris, grp = "Species")
```

Instead of grouping by species it just produces the summary for the entire data:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are passing a string, then convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
test_func <- function(dat, grp){
 dat %>%
    group_by(!! rlang::ensym(grp)) %>%
    summarise(N =  n(), .groups = 'drop')
 }
```

-testing

```
test_func(dat = iris, grp = "Species")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species        N
#* <fct>      <int>
#1 setosa        50
#2 versicolor    50
#3 virginica     50
```

Or another option is to use `across`

```
test_func <- function(dat, grp){
    dat %>%
       group_by(across(all_of(grp))) %>%
       summarise(N =  n(), .groups = 'drop')
 }
```